# Assigning to int from Compatible type int

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

In the bolded part, I am having **compile error**. some one help to find out error?
my code is given below...

```
void _multiDimensionalArray(){

    int row = 10;
    int column = 10;
    cout << "\n\n For a 2-Dimensional Array:>>>>" << endl;

    // 2D array is basically an array of pointers to arrays
    // dynamic array of size 100
    int pDoubleArray = new int*[row];
    for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {
        pDoubleArray[i] = new int[column];
    }
    // e) exchange rows: 0<------>9 and 3<------>4
    int (*ptemp)[10][1];        // temp is a pointer to an array of 10 ints
    ptemp = pDoubleArray;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        ptemp[i][0] = *(ptemp+4);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << ptemp[i] << " " ;
    }


 } // end of _multiDimensionalArray function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only reference the first value of the pointer. Once you reference the first pointer, at every other word length depending upon the data type, the reference is made.

Answer (score 2):

These objects have different types

```
int **pDoubleArray;

int (*ptemp)[10][1];
```

So you may not use the assignment

```
ptemp = pDoubleArray;
```

Even if to use casting the code will be invalid.

Take into account that this allocation is also invalid

```
int pDoubleArray = new int*[row];
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {
    pDoubleArray[i] = new int[column];
```

instead of column in the condition there has to be used row

```
for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
```

Take into account that you did not initialize the allocated arrays.

If you need to swap something as you are saying in the comments then swap each elements with each other. I do not see any sense to create a pointer to an array.

For example if you want to swap rows 1 and 9 then you could write simply

```
int *tmp = pDoubleArray[1];
pDoubleArray[1] = pDoubleArray[9];
pDoubleArray[9] = tmp;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int row = 10;
    int column = 10;

    int **p = new int *[row];
    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ ) p[i] = new int[column];

    for ( int i = 0; i < column; i++ ) p[1][i] = i;
    for ( int i = 0; i < column; i++ ) p[9][column - i - 1] = i;

    for ( int i = 0; i < column; i++ ) std::cout << p[1][i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < column; i++ ) std::cout << p[9][i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int *tmp = p[1];
    p[1] = p[9];
    p[9] = tmp;

    for ( int i = 0; i < column; i++ ) std::cout << p[1][i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < column; i++ ) std::cout << p[9][i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ ) delete [] p[i];
    delete []p;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As you see two rows were swapped.